# RayCastHit could not be found error message *Unity*

Tags: c#, scripting, unity-game-engine

I am following a tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Gx2tmhKq2g

and in the tutorial, the data type RayCastHit is used, however in MonoDevelop, this keyword isn't highlighted for me, so i assumed it could not be found... and then i got the error message 'The type/namespace name RayCastHit could not be found.'

I was wondering if i need to do something specific to resolve this problem or if it's just another one of my silly Unity mistakes :P

The code for my script so far is:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class RayCast : MonoBehaviour {

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    //if left mouse button clicked,
    // create ray cast from mouse clicked pos.

    Ray rayOrigin;
    RayCastHit hitInfo;

}
```

}

I may have moved the project from one folder to another after creation so im not sure if that's why it's confused... as i am using a dedicated folder to put all of my Unity projects in... (documents/UnityProjects/RayCastTutorial) where RayCastTutorial is the name of this project.

Thanks for being awesome and helping me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "c" in [RaycastHit](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit.html) needs to be lowercase, not uppercase.

So, at the end of your `Update` function, make sure your line looks like:

```
RaycastHit hitInfo;
```

Comment: yep... i just started to retype it and i just used the autocomplete/autosuggest when it appeared in that menu... although i was getting some weird errors after that and warnings but it seems to be ok now... thanks